# How can i include a simple news RSS Feed into a Html Page

Tags: html, rss

I have tried with the following

Opened this website

https://feed2js.org/index.php?s=build

and copy pasted the following news feed

http://www.indiainfoline.com/rss/latestnews.xml

and clciked on generate Javascript link

It generated the following

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://feed2js.org//feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.indiainfoline.com%2Frss%2Fbusinessnews.xml&chan=y&desc=1&utf=y"  charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript"></script>

<noscript>
<a href="http://feed2js.org//feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.indiainfoline.com%2Frss%2Fbusinessnews.xml&chan=y&desc=1&utf=y&html=y">View RSS feed</a>
</noscript>
```

When i pasted the following under a fiddle .

I am getting a error as "The RSS feed does not validate."

Could you please tell me how to display news feeds of any sample ??

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gur224qd/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with a valid RSS ?

Your RSS does'nt validate here: https://validator.w3.org/feed, when it is not just timed out.

Comment: Thank you , i am seen this website http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/newsarticle/rssfeeds/rssfeeds.php , could you please tell me how can i include any of the rss feed in the jsfiddle